# Export DataTable to Excel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

When calling this method, the whole page with html design ported to excel along with data.
I wants export data only, should not come with html design. I couldn't find the solution, Please some one help this to resolve.

```
 public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dtExportData)
        {
            string strReportName = string.Empty;
            //StringWriter oStringWriter = null;
            //Html32TextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = null;
            //TableOneDayPassReport.Visible = true;
            ExcelGrid.EnableViewState = false;
            ExcelGrid.DataSource = dtExportData;
            ExcelGrid.DataBind();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OwnTransportDetails.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            //TableOneDayPassReport.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            //Response.End();


            // strReportName = dtExportData.TableName;
            // Report_Month.InnerHtml = "<b>" + strReportName + " Report</b><br />";
            // ReportHead.Attributes.Add("style", "DISPLAY: block; VISIBILITY: visible");
            // TableOneDayPassReport.Visible = true;
            // //oStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            // //oHtmlTextWriter = new Html32TextWriter(oStringWriter);
            // ExcelGrid.EnableViewState = false;
            // ExcelGrid.DataSource = dtExportData;
            // ExcelGrid.DataBind();
            // Response.Clear();
            // Response.Buffer = true;
            // Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strReportName + ".xls");
            // Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            // TableOneDayPassReport.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
            // Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
            // HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            //// Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: check this my code @Suresh Savage

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the browser to handle the data as Microsoft Excel but return HTML data. Microsoft Excel is clever enough to display HTML data and shows the data.

If you only want to export data you should use libraries such as EPPlus or Microsoft's own SDK and create an Excel sheet on the server. Then, return this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

check this code by this code you can download .csv file in excel format

here you need to create folder download  and from that folder you need to give server path. `href="../../download/Orders.csv"`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
public partial class Admin_export_order : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DBAccess dbAcc = new DBAccess();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["admin_id"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("~/jbs/admin/login");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            view_edit_supplier_BAL objHelp = new view_edit_supplier_BAL();
            DataTable dtHelp = objHelp.SearchSupplier("where page = 'export_order'", 18);
            if (dtHelp != null && dtHelp.Rows.Count > 0)
                lblhelp_msg.Text = dtHelp.Rows[0][0].ToString().Replace("''", "'");
        }
        StreamWriter sw;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        export_bal objGet = new export_bal();
        ds = objGet.getDetails(5);

        try
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                sw = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/download/Orders.csv"), false, Encoding.Unicode);

                int iColCount = ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count;
                for (int h = 0; h < iColCount; h++)
                {
                    sw.Write(ds.Tables[i].Columns[h]);
                    if (h < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write("\t");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[i].Rows)
                {
                    for (int h = 0; h < iColCount; h++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[h]))
                        {
                            if (dr[h].ToString().Contains("\r\n"))
                            {
                                string newdata = dr[h].ToString();
                                string newcolumn = newdata.Replace("\r\n", "");
                                sw.Write(newcolumn);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                sw.Write(dr[h].ToString());

                            }
                        }
                        if (h < iColCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write("\t");
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                }
                sw.Close();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }


}





<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<table style="height: auto; width: 99.3%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
        align="left" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" width="8">
                <img height="8" width="8" alt="left bottom" src="../admin/images/top-left-corner.gif" />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="99%">
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="right" width="8">
                <img height="8" width="8" align="right" alt="bottom right" src="../admin/images/right-top-corner.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="36px" style="padding-left: 18px;">
                            <img src="images/category-img.gif" width="36" height="36" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="font_text_bold">
                            Export Orders
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="height: 660px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                                        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="padding-left: 7px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table width="99%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="height: auto;">
                                                        <tr class="box_hd_bg_for_every">
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" width="7">
                                                                <img src="images/left-add-pro.gif" alt="left" height="29" />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="font_text_bold" width="100%" align="center" style="padding-right: 200px;
                                                                width: 1500px">
                                                                Export Setup
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td align="right">
                                                                <img src="images/right-add-pro.gif" alt="right" height="29" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="Gray_blowtr" colspan="3">
                                                                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="2" height="10">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="2" align="left" class="font_text" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                                                            Export file will be readable in Microsoft Excel or equivalent applications for ease
                                                                            review of data. Please click on below download button to Export file for Orders.
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="height: 20px;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="2" align="center" style="height: 30px;">
                                                                            <a href="../../download/Orders.csv" class="setpostion">&nbsp;<img style="border: 0"
                                                                                src="images/download.gif" alt="Download" title="Export" />
                                                                                &nbsp;</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="height: 20px;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                                        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="padding-left: 7px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table width="99%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" style="height: auto;">
                                                        <tr class="box_hd_bg_for_every">
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top" width="7">
                                                                <img src="images/left-add-pro.gif" alt="left" height="29" />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="font_text_bold" width="100%" style="padding-right: 200px">
                                                                How to use this page
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td align="right">
                                                                <img src="images/right-add-pro.gif" alt="right" height="29" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="Gray_blowtr" colspan="3" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
                                                                padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblhelp_msg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr style="height: 20px;">
                                                            <td>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="bottom" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" width="8">
                <img height="8" width="8" alt="left bottom" src="images/bottom-left-corner.gif" />
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="99%">
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="right" width="8">
                <img height="8" width="8" align="right" alt="bottom right" src="images/bottom-right-corner.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Please move the Response.End(); line to onclick events and call the ExportToExcel(DataTable dtExportData) method.

And Response.End(); should not be inside of try...catch statements, it should be outside try...catch statements

Comment: Why shouldn't it be inside of the try...catch statements?